# Building workspace has encountered

Tags: javascript

I have a Dynamic WebProject in eclipse,i am trying to add .js files to WebContent/js folder.
While adding i am getting Building Workspace has encountered a problem,Error occurred during the build.how to avoid this ?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried creating Dynamic web project on my side with such structure as you have explained.

And its working fine. Try creating it again or clean and build. If possible share your error console. You can also try creating your project in NEW WORKSPACE.

[image]